# wso2 apim - token api issue for users in secondary user store

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

The WSO2 APIM version is 3.2.0.

Created a JBDC secondary userstore `opera` in WSO2 APIM and added some users say `user1`.

There was an application created in devportal - **GUI_APP**

When I try to access the token API with the user in opera, I'm getting the below error.
`"Users in the tenant domain : opera do not have access to application admin_GUI_APP_PRODUCTION"`

*API details below:*

Request URL:
https://{APIM_IP}:8243/token

Request Method:
POST

Request Headers:
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization:Basic (base64 encoded key:secret of GUI_APP)

Request Body:
grant_type:password
username:user1@opera
password:{pwd}

Kindly let me know what change needs to be done, to get the token for users in  secondary user store .

Answer (score 0):

The user store domain should be prepended to the username in the following format. The `@` symbol is used to append the tenant domain to the username.

`UserStoreDomain/Username`

Also, it is not mandatory to prepend the user store domain. When the user store domain is not prepended, it will first search the username in the PRIMARY and then search for all the secondary user stores.

Comment: If the username is given as opera/user1 (in my case), I'm getting Authentication failed error even though the correct password is given.
`Authentication failed for OPERA/user1`